# Is there any process to parse database files of mongodb without mongodb client or mongodb tools?

Tags: java, c#, mongodb

I have a collection***.wt file of mongodb. I want to access this file directly from C# or Java without installing mongodb tools.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the existing tools?

Comment: For an experiment, I was doing so.

Answer (score 0):

if you have remote MongoDb server then you can easily access data from DB by any programming language (C# , java etc). to do that you need DB connection library for those specifically language and framework...

Here i give two link for JAVA spring boot framework tutorial [mongodb-crud](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/boot/spring-boot-mongodb-crud-operations-example/) , [crud-operations for MongoDB](https://reviewdb.io/posts/1503156546006/crud-operations-using-spring-boot-mongodb)

many more tutorial and sample code available in internet . to find this you need to searching by your favorite search engine

Comment: I want to take the database files (collection files of wt format) from the MongoDB server location to my local pc and parse those without mongodb client. Is that possible? If possible then how can be done?